# Bad performance after color count

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a problem with bad performance after implementing this code into my Excel list to count the filled cells without a color in the set range:

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor And Not datax.Value = vbNullString Then
           CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

I use this one as well to count yellow and red cells on the same page in the set range, but it doesn't lower the performance as much as the one above:

```
Function Farbsumme(Bereich As Range, Farbe As Integer)
    Dim Zelle As Range
    Application.Volatile
    For Each Zelle In Bereich
        If Zelle.Interior.ColorIndex = Farbe Then
            Farbsumme = Farbsumme + 1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Is there something I did wrong? Anything I could do better to increase the performance?

Comment: Could it be that you are using the formula in too many cells? Maybe changing Calculation to manual will help?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I use it for atleast 10-20 cells per column. And with 10 differend collums, i use it very often. I use it for expired or soon expired keys. With over 6000 keys, and differend people working on the same list, i like to keep it automatik. We had alot of problems with wrong numbers in the past.

Comment: Just for testing purpose does your code fasten up if you remove `And Not datax.Value = vbNullString`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout sadly, no. still need 5-10 sec per change to calculate the new number. The range is <100 cells, but still like 5-10 sec for every change and new calculation.

Comment: does that workbook have lot of formulas?

Comment: Also what did you mean by `per change` ? Did you mean change of colors? If yes then how are the changes happening?

Comment: Do you also have a `sheet Change` or `Selection change` event?

Comment: @SiddharthRout mainly 2 "complex" formulas. The both i posted above. Just a few sums besides those two. With `per change` i mean changing the color or numbre of keys bby adding new to the list or mark them as expired. I dont change the sheet with a formular, if you are asking for that. There are 10 sheets for differend keys. There is no formular that work with more then the sheet its on

Comment: possible for me to see the file?

Comment: @SiddharthRout sadly no. The file contains private and company intern informations.

Comment: Have you tried to use Application.Screenupdating = false / true

Comment: Then I can only shoot in the dark :D Check these `1` Are there anyother VBA code which is interferring for example "Worksheet_SelectionChange" or "Worksheet_Change" or something similar? `2` Try that function in a new File. Is it slow there as well? `3` Try using `Application.Screenupdating = False` `4` Any Add-Ins which are interferring? `5` Any hidden sheets which have lot of formulas? `6` Any named ranges with formulas. Can check formula manager. `7` Any links to other files? `8` any queries which could be interferring... Phew! Etc Etc

Comment: @Lutscha I just started working with excel, with `ScreenUpdating` you mean putting `false`at the beginning of my macro and `true` at the end? I tried that, but didnt speed it up either.

Comment: @SiddharthRout [link](https://imgur.com/a/NWHt7eU) there are no macros beside the 2 I am useing right now. Not sure if the Screenshot can help you. But thats what i use. I am rly not good with Excel, so maybe i did something wrong. Verything works fine, just the speed is bad. If i change smth in a row like the color from `no color` to `expired=red` i need to click on the cell with the `count`. after that, i can `shift+enter` to calculate the new count directly. Without that, the new count will just apply after saving and reopening. This new calculation after `shift+enter` will take up to 10sec

Comment: @SiddharthRout [link](https://imgur.com/a/Yct6hOS) this is a custom sheet to show you the syntax of my lists. As soon as i `pause` the macros, everything can be changed and worked with without any lag. If i start the macros again, even while changing rows like the Type of Key (1,2,3,..) the list is lagging for 2-5 secs. Just the load icon and sometimes no responce from excel for a few secounds.

Comment: @Psychosun Remove application.volatile from your other function and try again.

Comment: @ImranMalek WOW. I removed it, and its WAY faster now! As far as i can say, just like 1 sec or less for new forced calculation with `shift+enter`. Thank you! Time to learn and google why this one line just killed my whole code. :D

Comment: This could probably be written a lot more efficiently by counting all the cells at once, perhaps using `SpecialCells`. For example if the cells are colored using Conditional Formatting then `rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameFomatConditions)`  would return a range of the cells with the same *conditional* formatting as the first cell in the range.

Comment: Also, what values are you passing as Farbe? [ColorIndex](https://analystcave.com/excel-vba-colorindex-vs-vba-color-property/) should be a value between 1 and 56 only. Also the data type for Farbe should technically be Variant. (See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/Excel.ColorIndex )

Comment: @ashleedawg TBH i am just glad that it works now. Its the first time i use vba. :D But `farbe`is just something between 1 and 56. Just to indicate the color. I just use red(3) an yellow(6).

Comment: @ImranMalek @ashleedawg  I dont know why, maybe you can help here aswell. If i add new Keys, the count formular change it directly. So if i have 3 keys and add 2, it will go to 5 in the same moment. But if i change color of the cells (expired) it doesnt change until i `shift+enter` after clicking into the formular or i save and restart the excel file. Is it possible to change that? Without to force every single cell with volatile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using the other function in your sheet and every time it recalculates the `application.volatile` slows down your code.

Removing `application.volatile` might solve your problem.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Volatile) is some nice straightforward information about this function for further explaination :)